# How to get clientX and clientY from key event in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, dom

I am using a keydown event and not be able to get clientX and clientY to use them to display a menu.
I listen on @ key then display a list of users in a small menu but I am not be able to get the clientX neither the clientY or/and pageY and pageX too .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the position of the parent element, so that you know where to place the child element.

[Here is an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-euz43x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
    const input: HTMLInputElement = event.target as any;
    const value = input.value;

    if (!value.endsWith('@')) return;

    const { x, y, width, height } = input.getBoundingClientRect();

    console.log(`Menu under input should be at [${x}, ${y + height}]`);
```

Comment: Thank you! but I need the menu to be displayed over the textarea (input). when I type @ a list of users will be displayed beside the @ key .  t

Comment: @Majed you place it however you want, I'm just giving you the logic. Adapt to your own needs.